# SQL Server Always Encrypted with .NET Core not compatible

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I'm trying to use the Always Encrypted feature of SQL Server 2016 with .NET Core and seems like it can not be used (yet).  Trying to import the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider` from Nuget, I get an error stating it is not compatible:

> Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider 1.0.201501028 is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)

Any ideas on how/where to get a compatible version?

Comment: Currently being tracked here:  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9193

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am a Program Manager at Microsoft

<s>Always Encrypted is currently not supported in .NET Core. It is on our roadmap, we don't have a timeline for it yet.</s>

This is now supported. See answers below.

Comment: For those interested, similar Q/A here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175489/column-encryption-in-asp-mvc-app-with-sql-server-2016-using-net-core-ef-core

Comment: @Jakub Szymaszek - Microsoft
What about now , is there any new updates regarding this issue?

Comment: What about now?

Comment: any update for this issue ? I think this is major issue for security that MS left behind when catching up update for framework and it does't well organize with other product.

Comment: Any update after Mocrosoft.Data.SqlClient 1.1 release ? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhzRzRBDTyE)

Answer (score 17):

Always Encrypted is now supported in .Net Core 3.1 LTS.

You have to use the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider nuget package

```
    Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider -Version 1.1.1
```

Make sure you have a Keyvault setup.

FOR DEBUGGING your account in VS has to have sufficent rights to access the keyvault. (When published the app itself has to have sufficent rights :  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/managed-identity) Get and List permissions alone might not be sufficient.

Then in program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
//namespaces etc omitted
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
         {
             var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
             {
                 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                 var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                     new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                         azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                 config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                 SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                         azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                 SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(customProviders: new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>(capacity: 1, comparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 {
                     { 
                         SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider
                     }
                 });                     
             }
         })
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
         });
    private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "https://YOURKEYVAULT.vault.azure.net/";
}
```

In StartUp.cs ConfigureServices:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
//Code omitted
services.AddDbContext<EnitiesModel>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntitiesModel"))));
```

Make sure your connectionstring contains the Column Encryption Setting=Enabled parameter:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"EntitiesModel": "Server=SOMESERVER.database.windows.net;Database=SOMEDB;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Integrated Security=False;
MultipleActiveResultSets=true;persist security info=True;user id=SOMEDBACCOUNT;password=SOMEPASSWORD;
Column Encryption Setting=enabled;"   
  }
```

Small gotcha : If you used DB scaffolding make sure the Model connectionstring  has the Column Encryption Setting aswell!
(if you did not change it, it is standard inside the DBModel class after scaffolding with a VS warning)

This should get you up and running...

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use this with a key vault with an app registration? I'm developing an app that will be deployed in IIS not Azure. So I don't have an app service. But I am using keyvaults to store connection string and tokens. So I have an app registration in Azure which has access to the key vault. The app registration doesn't support MSI so I can't use your method. But I also can't find how I'm supposed to get it working in my situation either.

Comment: Maybe via an app configuration?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-key-vault-references-dotnet-core?tabs=cmd%2Ccore2x

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to get it working by setting up the SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider to get a token by using the app registration's client id and secret with the ActiveDirectory ClientCredential class.

Comment: I've read through dozens of pages of documentation and examples trying to get azure based column encryption to work with EF. This is maybe the only example that does all three. +1.

Comment: One thing to add:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider
is NOT the same as Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider

Most outdated documentation is using the .SqlServer namespace which was half my problem.

Comment: Thank you. Been trying to get it working for days. You saved me.

Comment: Can always encrypted with ef core work without  AzureKeyVaultProvider ? But with windows Certificates ?

Answer (score 6):

It's now supported in [.NET Core 3.0 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-5/), which provides a new [SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient) supporting Always Encrypted and more. See this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18276#issuecomment-489723661) for more info.

For the Key Vault provider, you need to use [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider) instead.

Comment: That isn't the Key Vault provider though, but I think support in SqlClient for column encryption does enable them to do the key vault provider work.

Comment: Key Vault provider is also updated 2 months ago: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider supports .NET Core 2.1 and later.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the Program.cs from Tim's answer above, but for apps registered with Azure App Registration:

```
namespace Sample
{
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
         {
             var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
             {
                 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(keyVaultEndpoint);
                 var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                     new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                         azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                 
                 SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider = new SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                         azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                 SqlConnection.RegisterColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProviders(customProviders: new Dictionary<string, SqlColumnEncryptionKeyStoreProvider>(capacity: 1, comparer: StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                 {
                     {
                         SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider.ProviderName, sqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider
                     }
                 });
             }
         })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });

       private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "RunAs=App;AppId=<app ID>;TenantId=<tenant ID>.onmicrosoft.com;AppKey=<app secret>";
   }
 }
```