# Column encryption in ASP MVC app with SQL Server 2016 using .net Core / EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I am trying to use the "Always Encrypted" feature in SQL Server 2016 to encrypt some columns. I used [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/07/05/developing-databases-using-always-encrypted-with-sql-server-data-tools/) as a guide to set the columns as encrypted in SSDT.

That part goes fine, it's when I attempt to query the data from the application that I get an error. According to the docs I need to add this:

```
column encryption setting=enabled
```

to my connection string. This does not appear to be supported in Entity Framework Core. I get this error:

> column encryption setting=enabled is not supported

I tried using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build the string as well and the ability to add that setting is not there.  It does appear to be there in .NET 4.6.

So, is anyone aware of a way to connect to an SQL server instance from a .NET Core application using Always Encrypted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Always Encrypted with .NET Core not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always Encrypted is currently not supported on .Net Core

You can find the list of supported frameworks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147923.aspx)

Adding Support for .NET core is on our roadmap, we do not have timeline for it yet

Please follow [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18276#issuecomment-314610769) for updates

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Otherwise this answer is just opinion.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the Answer, but, I am a part of Always Encrypted team :)

Comment: Haha that is awesome, but to play devils advocate, anyone could say that! It's just good practice to link to some evidence, perhaps there's a github issue or roadmap?

Comment: You can find the list of supported frameworks here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147923.aspx

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, is support planned?  Can you possibly give any indication of whether it is a 1.X feature or later?

Comment: Hi Brian, It is on our roadmap, we don't have a timeline for it yet.

Comment: I'm also with Brian here.  Have built everything using .NET Core and now really the only missing piece is getting AE to work.  Would really love to use AE instead of incorporating a custom version.  Any updates to this roadmap?  Maybe an alpha version to test out with .NET core?  ;-)

Comment: Has there been any progress on the .NET Core framework regarding Always Encrypted?

Comment: A status update would be appreciated. Or a link to the roadmap or issue in github.

Comment: I followed the ticket trail to this new ticket that's tracking the current state of the feature: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9193

Comment: This is now supported, see my answer on this stackoverflow question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

Always Encrypted is now supported in the [.NET Core 3.0 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-3-0-preview-5/) through the new [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://github.com/dotnet/sqlclient) data provider for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: yup - but I can't find any samples re: how to implement Always Encrypted using this new package.  Does any one have any idea how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by MS folks - Always Encrypted is currently not supported on .Net Core.

- We had the same situation, finally we had to make the **Core WebApp to target .NET Full Framework**, there is no other option.
- i.e., Currently not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1)
  Compatible with net452 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2)
- From forums - "Eventhough EF Core could work for AE feature, but still the underlying .NET Core SQL Client currently does not support for AE, and it will be in their (MS + Opensource ontributors) future mile stone to support it"

Please refer this [GitHub page](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18276#issuecomment-314610769) for any recent updates on this issue:

Comment: Had same situation so we created a new project in the solution that targeted .NET46.  Thought that would work but your MVC Web App also has to target .NET46.

Answer (score 1):

It just mention [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhzRzRBDTyE)

> Microsoft.data.sqlclient

Answer (score 1):

As of .net Core 3.1 this is supported.
I have it running in production scenario
See my Answer on this stackoverflow question (Using EFCore and Azure KeyVault) : [SQL Server Always Encrypted with .NET Core not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible)