# Is there proper support available in.net core 3.0 for SQL Always Encrypted with Azure Key Vault?

Tags: sql, .net-core, key, always-encrypted, ansible-vault

I am trying to implement/understand SQL Always Encrypted in .net core 3.0 and Azure KV.

I was able to successfully implement a working solution using MSFT's own provided documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-always-encrypted-azure-key-vault, with VS2019 and full .NET.

But, for my use case, I would like this to be done using .net core.

I have seen that there is preview of this out now, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/.

// Create a SqlConnectionStringBuilder.
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

According to the documentation, this shoould work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder?view=netcore-3.0

But it is not. What did I do wrong?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Error is Reference does not exist.

Comment: any adding reference for Microsoft.data.sqlclient, yet ?

Answer (score 0):

On 3.0 it is not, on .Net Core 3.1 with EFCore 3.1 it is supported 
see my answer here : [SQL Server Always Encrypted with .NET Core not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible)