# .NET Core 3.1 Always Encrypted

Tags: always-encrypted, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am getting the following error when using .NET Core 3.1 and SQL Always Encrypted. Is this supported in 3.1? Perhaps I am missing something here..

```
Keyword not supported: 'column encryption setting'.
```

Currently have the following packages installed

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
```

Comment: see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Always Encrypted with .NET Core not compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027953/sql-server-always-encrypted-with-net-core-not-compatible)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Needed to add the following package reference to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` (see [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/)) and use this **`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`** and NOT `System.Data.SqlClient`.

```
    using (var conn = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
    }
```