# .NET 5.0 SQL Connection String with Always Encrypt Enable

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, connection-string, sql-server-2017

I have a .NET 5.0 project that is connected to SQL Server 2017. I am using always encrypt to encrypt a couple columns because they include sensitive data. However, I am getting the error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'column encryption
> setting'.

**Connection String:**

```
Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=true; Column Encryption Setting=enabled
```

**Opening the Connection:**

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_options.Value.DefaultConnection))
        {
            await con.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_name", con))
            {
              ....
            }
        }
```

**Exception:**

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'column encryption setting'.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Students.SQL.Repository.AuthenticationRepository.SignIn(UserDto user) in C:\Students\development\Students\Students.SQL\Repository\AuthenticationRepository.cs:line 24
   at Students.Controllers.AccountController.Authenticate(UserDto userDto) in C:\Students\development\Students\Students\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 33
   at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 3.1 Always Encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826833/net-core-3-1-always-encrypted)

Comment: @zhulien It appeared to have .Net Core 3.1 as requirement.