# .NET Core 2.2 > Always Encrypted Not Supported

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, always-encrypted

I am getting the following error when using .NET Core 2.2 and SQL Always Encrypted. Is this supported in 2.2?

> Keyword not supported: 'column encryption setting'.

Actually, I run DB migration in my AppContext constructor as you can see there.

```
public SenSightsContext(DbContextOptions<SenSightsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.Migrate();
    }
```

It was not working before and it was giving me an exception, Which I fixed by installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.
Now it is giving me the error on SeedData Method as shown below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, AppUserManager userManager, ILoggerManager loggerManager)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        //custom exception middleware.
        app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(loggerManager);

        //Seed Data
        SeedData(roleManager, userManager).Wait();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SenSights API V1");
            //c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  // Set Swagger UI at apps root
        });
        var path = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Uploads", "ProfileImages");

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path),
            RequestPath = "/ProfileImages"
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Following is the Stack

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
> at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.d__61.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.<BufferlessMoveNext>d__12.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.d__11.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.<FirstOrDefault_>d__165`1.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\First.cs:line 151
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.d__3.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.d__7.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 118
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.d__10.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 112
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__21`1.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.d__33.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at CMAD_API.Startup.d__6.MoveNext() in C:\WorkSpaces\Markitech\Sensight\sensights_backend\SenSights-API\Startup.cs:line 256

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Always Encrypted is now supported in .NET Core 3.0 +

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core 3.1 Always Encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826833/net-core-3-1-always-encrypted)

Comment: @Charlieface No, My .NET Core version is not 3.1, It is 2.2, I've seen this link already and i know Alway Encrypted is supported in 3.0+ versions, Actually i don't want to update my .NET Core version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add the following package reference Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (see nuget) and use this Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient.

It is supported in .NET Core 3.0+ versions